# Enter Parameters Value Error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I made a search form that filters a table and runs a query. it works perfectly but every time I open the query I get an error. If I just click ok everything is displayed like it should be, I just have this annoying error message. I am very new to SQL coding but could this be my issue

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Search Form]![Source] & "*"
```

I used this line to filter the results in the query.

Comment: There are supposed to be * in those quotes, not sure why they are not showing.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the query in **SQL** view, you'll something like:

```
Select Field1, Field2
From YourTable
Where Field2 Like "*" & [Forms]![Search Form]![Source] & "*"
```

If you just ignore the parameter value when running the query, that will evaluate to:

```
Select Field1, Field2
From YourTable
Where Field2 Like "**"
```

which will allow any value for Field2 except *Null* which is why "it works" for you.

To avoid the popup box, remove the parameter, reducing to:

```
Select Field1, Field2
From YourTable
Where Field2 Like "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is looking for whatever is in the [source] textbox on the form named [Search Form]. So the query should be loaded from that form not by itself.